# Calculating list of all files in S3 directory resulting in compilation error

Tags: scala

I am trying to calculate size of all files in a given S3 folder using Scala. The following functions gives a compilation error.

```
def getFolderSize(filePath: String): Long = {
    val objects = s3client.listObjectsWithPrefix(bucket, filePath.replace(s"s3://${bucket_name}/", ""))
    var size: Long = 0
        for (obj <- objects) {
            size += obj.getSize()
        }
    return size
  }
```

Could you please advise me what I am doing wrong here?

**Error:**

```
error: value += is not a member of Long
Expression does not convert to assignment because:value getSize is not a member of String
expansion: size = size.+(obj.<getSize: error>())
 size += obj.getSize()
      ^
```

Comment: That error is weird but it seems the real problem is that `getSize` is wrong. - BTW, if you are using **Scala** you should refrain from pointless mutability, this is a simple `prefixs.map(_.getSize).sum`

Comment: The error isn't weird: `obj` is a `String`, so `obj.getSize` is invalid, as it clearly indicates.  Where is `objects` defined? And yeah, don't write python code in scala ...

Comment: @Dima - Thanks for the reply. I have added val objects assignment now.

Comment: You need yo use `s3client` to request information about each bucket. Your query only gave you a list of names (`String`s).